# Vim key mapping works in command editor, not in .vimrc - why?

Tags: vim

When I create the following key mapping via the command buffer it works as expected moving the cursor 5 lines down:

```
map ^[[1;3B 5<Down>
```

When I add it to my .vimrc file so that it works across sessions, pressing Alt+Down moves backwards 1 line (to somewhere not vertically above - maybe it's going to a previous sentence). My :map output is this:

```
0             ^
^[[1;3B       5<Down>
n  gx         <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Why doesn't this vimrc mapping work similarly to what I type in the command buffer?

My version of vim is:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan 10 2014 00:22:49)
Included patches: 1-135
Compiled by <cygwin@cygwin.com>
```

---

**UPDATE**

There are 2 issues.

1. my version of Vim doesn't understand `map <M-Down> 5<Down>` but does understand `map <M-Down> 5j`
2. Something in my .vimrc file prevents `map <M-Down> 5j` from working. I had to put a bunch of hacks in to get "normal" vim behavior in my Cygwin environment:

> ```
> "==================
> " Keyboard trouble
> "=================
>
> " Every so often I am using a system that inserts a A, B, C, or D
> " when using the arrow keys within the Vim editors insert mode.
> " Vim is for VI Improved. While I did not dig into the exact reasons
> " as to why (terminal emulation?) it happens, it is quite annoying.
> set nocompatible
> "set term=cons25
>
> " This fixes Cygwin's vim's page up, home, end etc. keys
> " http://superuser.com/questions/480215/
> " how-to-map-pagedown-and-pageup-keys-to-function-normally
> set term=mintty
> set backspace=2 " backspace on Cygwin Windows Objy was not deleting properly. 
> " But this doesn't solve other cursor movements like
> "home and end
> "source /home/sarnobat/.vim/cscope_maps.vim
> "g:CCTreeCscopeDb = "/home/sarnobat/cscope/cscope.files"
>
> "==============================
> " Key bindings
> "==============================
> map 0 ^
> ```

Comment: How did you enter `^[` in Vim's command-line and in your `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: In the command buffer I used Ctrl-v. In vimrc I copied and pasted it from the command buffer.

Comment: FYI, similar problem with `map ^[[1;3D b` . Works in command buffer, not in vimrc. It's reasons like this I don't yet buy Cygwin as a UNIX-like feel for Windows.

Comment: Food for thought: 1) Use [nnoremap](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) 2) Take a look at `:h map-alt-keys` and `:h map-which-keys` 3) The "vim way" is to avoid the arrow keys 4) You may want to look at `:h ctrl-u` and `:h ctrl-d` as an alternative 5) Relative number might be helpful to you, see `:h 'rnu'` 6) `H`, `M`, and `L` motions may also be helpful, see `:h H`

Comment: Thanks for the tips Peter. I'll post a followup after getting around to trying those.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand those characters: `^[[1;3B`. In [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) you can choose the `Alt` key as letter `M` and the arrow letter as `down`, so:

```
map <M-down> 5<Down>
```

will work in either command-line and from your `vimrc` file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get the same behavior whether I use your or my version. Even if that doesn't solve my problem, at least I know it's something specific to my environment. Being on Cygwin I'm sure introduces issues that aren't there on *nix systems.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the following:

```
map <M-down> 5j
```

Tried it on cygwin and it worked. hjkl is the preferred method of navigating left, down, up and right.

Comment: No effect. Good to know you got it to work on Cygwin though. I even tried it after eliminating everything else in my .vimrc file. Then it doesn't move backwards, but just stays in the same place.

Comment: Oh wait, this does work with the 5j syntax. But not the 5<Down> syntax IF I remove everything else from my vimrc file. You've got me going in the right direction.

Comment: Try the following:

map <M-down> :normal! 5j<cr>

If you have j mapped to something else this will perform j with the default mapping

Comment: Damn it. That doesn't work either. I really got my hopes up for a moment.