# macvim mapping works when set in command line but not in vimrc

Tags: vim, macvim

I want to map cmd-left/right to W and w to navigate splits.  So I tested right from the command line (in normal mode):

```
:map <D-Left> <C-w>W
```

And it works like a charm.  When I had the same line (minus the colon, obviously) in my .vimrc, the mapping is not set.

The [closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106741/vim-key-mapping-works-in-command-editor-not-in-vimrc-why) I found seem to be related to cygwin only.  I also don't believe I am running against a terminal hijacking issue (launching macvim from the finder doesn't change the behaviour) nor does CMD-left/right seem to be an OS wide shortcut.

I must be missing something terribly simple here but I can't find out what.

Thanks in advance for any help/hints

Comment: (1) Use `nnoremap` instead of `map`. (2) How can you tell the map isn't set?  What is the output of: `:map <D-Left>`?

Comment: Just an auxilliary remark: you wrote "minus the colon, obviously", but it is allowed to use the colon at the beginning of a line in a vim script, even if it looks better without

Comment: @lcd047 Sorry I should have said.  Result is `* <Home>` which is the behaviour I see (going the beginning of line).  Same behaviour with `nnoremap`.

Comment: @yolenoyer thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: Then you have something else that sets the same key combination.  Sadly, there is no easy way to tell what that something might be.

Comment: You can try `:verbose map <D-Left>` to find in which script the mapping were defined for the last time

Comment: @yolenoyer please make an answer with your latest comment and I will accept it as it allowed me to actually solve my problem. There is indeed another file which set the same key combination and you allowed me to find it: Macvim has .gvimrc which is sourced *after* ~/.vimrc, of all things.  Thanks you both for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `:verbose map <D-Left>` to find in which script the mapping were defined for the last time

Comment: This actually allowed me to find that Macvim has .gvimrc which is sourced *after* `~/.vimrc`, In the case of `<D-Left>`, you can prevent MacVim to set a bunch of HIG compatible mappings by using `let macvim_skip_cmd_opt_movement=1`. For those interested, the file is located in `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/gvimrc` (there is also a `.vimrc`).